# ADF Copy Activity from Source Azure Synapse Analytics Target ADLSGen2 Storage account

Tags: azure-data-factory, parquet

Created a ADF copy activity from Source Azure Synapse Analytics to Target ADLSGen2 as parquet file. Source record count is around 500000000.Source table is not partitioned and also distribution is Round Robin. When executed it took around 5 hours to complete. Tried Dynamic range using Date column with degree of copy parallelism (15). Below are the options I tried.

[image: Copy Activity Source]

[image]

Is there any better option to increase performance while loading the data from source to target , also can we do parallel copy in target destination? Please help on this Thanks